# weird positioning top bar zurb foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Hi guys so a site I've been working on is acting up and has randomly re-positioined itself wierdly on the top bar and I have no idea why. I thought everything was fine before, however recently I saw the site and it just so happened that theres a wierd space at the top of the page between the nav bar and the window url. Can someone inspect it and help me figure out whats causing this and if there would be a quick or easy fix. The site is [www.omegadesignla.com](http://www.omegadesignla.com) 
and any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Omega Design | LA</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Web development and printing services serving the greater los angeles area">
      <meta name="keywords" content="web development, printing, graphics design, los angeles, santa clarita">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
              <span><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logofinal.png"></a><span>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Contact us</a></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Services</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="services.html#printing">Print Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Web Development</a></li>
                   <!--  <li><a href="services.html">Promotional Items</a></li> -->
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li> -->
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>    
  <div class="container">
    <header>
```

Comment: thanks for the answers guys i will check this later tonight when i get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a line `"&nbsp;&nbsp;    "` right after the `body` tag. Remove it and this should reposition the navigation bar correctly.

I just realized that you can only see this if you 'inspect element' in development tools.

If you can edit the page's source, make sure that the `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>` comes right after `<body>`. Right now, there is a blank line (line 16).

Comment: i see what you are talking about though, not sure what is creating that line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to solve this problem:

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason this works is that there is a blank space in the body, which will render a character, creating a line. Although what you are doing works, it's not a good practice because of inheritance reasons, plus it creates a property that really shouldn't be there.

Comment: this worked but it made the alignment on some of the other elements off.